# Two men, one woman, an antenna and a camera

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a SciFi horror involving two men and one woman who go out into the forest searching for UFO sightings and end up with bruises from late night events which occurred in the forest involving an antenna and an opening as two men cross wires together while the female watches.

The two men get their hands dirty in the late night fixing an old radio and putting the antenna in the opening of the radio when they here a noise in the bush they look at the female currently adjusting her skirt who has a look of fear on her face yet also a smile on her face like it excites her.

As the two men huddle against the females body for "warmth" the noise stops and the end.

Comment: Was this a movie? Do you know when you saw this? You can [edit] your post to add anything else you remember in!

Comment: Is there anything sci-fi about the story? People searching for UFO sightings is something that happens in real life. Is there a real UFO in the story?